# Import multiple data frames CSV - column separation

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv file with multiple data frames that are all separated by a column (So 4 columns of data, empty column, 4 columns of data, etc.). Is there a nice way to read in the file and have R create a separate df for each of those contiguous sets of columns? Then I would be able to use lapply across all of these dfs.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `So 4 columns of data, empty row, 4 columns of data, etc.` you meant `So 4 columns of data, empty *column*, 4 columns of data, etc.`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in the whole csv file, then use `lapply` to separately capture each four-column data frame into a list. Then use `rbind` to stack all the data frames into a single data frame.

```
dat = read.csv("YourFile.csv")

# Set this based on how many separate data frames are in your csv file
num.df = ncol(dat)/5  # Per @zx8754's comment

# This will tell the function the column numbers where
# each data frame starts
start.cols = seq(1, 1 + 5*(num.df-1), 5)

df.list = lapply(start.cols, function(x) {

  # Capture the next 4 columns
  df = dat[, x:(x+3)]

  # Use whatever names are appropriate here. This is just
  # to make sure all of the data frames have the same column names
  # so that rbind won't throw an error
  names(df) = c(paste0("col", 1:4))
  return(df)
})

# rbind all the data frames into a single data frame
df = do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

Comment: Number of data.frames could be guessed. `num.df <- ncol(dat)/5`

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your thorough response.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `colClasses`:

Example data:

```
  h1 h2 h3     h1.1 h2.1 h3.1     h1.2 h2.2 h3.2
1  1  6  3       1    8    8        1    5    2
2  2  1  1       6    5    8        1    3    1
3  3  2  6       1    2    3        1    2    5
```

Then you can loop through the number of dataframes you wan't and read the file:

```
ngroups <- 3 #number of dataframes to read
datacols <- 3 #number of columns to read
fulldata <- list()
for (i in 1:ngroups) {
  nskip <- (datacols+1)*(i-1)
  cols.to.read <- c(rep("NULL", nskip), rep(NA, datacols), rep("NULL", (datacols+1)*(ngroups-i+1)-1)) #creates a list of NULLs and NAs. NULLs = don't read, NA = read
  fulldata[[i]] <- read.csv("test.csv", colClasses=cols.to.read)
}
```

Result:

```
fulldata
[[1]]
  h1 h2 h3
1  1  6  3
2  2  1  1
3  3  2  6

[[2]]
  h1.1 h2.1 h3.1
1    1    8    8
2    6    5    8
3    1    2    3

[[3]]

  h1.2 h2.2 h3.2
1    1    5    2
2    1    3    1
3    1    2    5
```

This works, but I believe the answers reading the file only once would be faster, since reading the same file over and over again doesn't sound like the optimal procedure.

Answer (score 0):

First read in all your data into one large dataframe:

```
maindf <- read.table(yourfile)
```

Lets say n is the number of dataframes inside your csv file:

```
for (i in 0:n-1){
  assign(paste0("df",i+1),maindf[,(1+4*i):(4+4*i)])
}
```

The result should be n dataframes that can be accessed like this: df1, df2,...dfn.
I didnt test it, because no sample data was provided.